# Transfer data between two tables

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I need to transfer data from one table to another one in the same page in Rails. I searched for tutorials on the internet but didn't found something that I could use, maybe I missed some keyword or something. I could try to do it from scratch but i think this is a common thing so I don't want to reinvent the wheel here. I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

Imagine that you have people that work on one place but they can be transferred to another place and so on. I would like to know if someone has a tutorial or some guidance about how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm still googling it, I'm just a bit lost...

Comment: This is likely a JavaScript problem. There are jQuery plugins that do this.

Comment: are you talking of database tables or html tables?

Comment: I'm talking about both. html tables that represent database tables.

Answer (score 1):

**DRAGULA**

[image]
*Image source: http://thenextweb.com/dd/2015/07/20/less-of-a-drag-maaaaaaaan*

- Demo: https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/
- Repo:
  https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula
- CDN via `.erb`:

_

```
<%= javascript_include_tag("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/3.7.1/dragula.min.js") %>
```

---

**IMPLEMENTATION**

Implementation is up to you. Help: https://dragula-slackin.herokuapp.com/